# How can I find my Snowflake bill within Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Usually I get my Snowflake invoices through email, but I'd like to track my consumption within Snowflake.

I've found a way to find my usage data from the console, but not mapped to actual consumption in dollars.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the new org tables check the new org tables REMAINING_BALANCE_DAILY and USAGE_IN_CURRENCY_DAILY:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/organization-usage/usage_in_currency_daily.html
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/organization-usage/remaining_balance_daily.html

Some notes:

- The contract items view should show the consumption-related products invoiced for, and the usage_in_currency view shows all the information in the monthly usage statement.
- The daily usage numbers in org_usage may not be finalized. These numbers can be refreshed for the past several days, especially storage usage.
- Once a month closes the data should never change and should tie exactly to the usage statements.
- Also check the views RATE_SHEET_DAILY and CONTRACT_ITEMS: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/organization-usage.html#organization-usage-views